# ¿Son los archivos creados visibles en todas las ramas?

Tags: javascript, git

Tengo las siguientes ramas:

1. master
2. code-review
3. dev

Si creo un archivo en dev se supone que este sólo es visible dentro de esa rama.

Me explico mejor. Estoy dentro del área de trabajo de la rama dev, si creo un archivo estando parado en esa rama, se supone que dicho archivo sólo será visible en esa rama. Si me muevo a la rama master, el archivo no debería de aparecer o ¿si? y este sólo pasa a ser invisible hasta que se convierte en un commit, de lo contrario, es visible para todas las ramas.

Cree un archivo de prueba en la rama dev, pero, cuando me cambio de rama, puedo verlo en todas las ramas. Al ser un archivo sólo de prueba, no quería hacer un commit de él.

Answer (score 4):

### Ramas y archivos

Asumiendo que tienes un proyecto con las siguientes ramas:

```
 + master
 + code-review
 + dev
```

Si te encuentras en la rama `dev` y creas un nuevo directorio o archivo allí, los cambios aplicados en ella no se reflejarán en las otras ramas.

Por ejemplo, si creas un directorio:

```sh
mkdir "Directorio"
```

O creas un archivo:

```sh
touch archivo.js
```

Y luego guarda los cambios:

```sh
git add .
git commit -m "Cambios aplicados"
```

No deberán reflejarse en la rama `master`, a menos que, te dirijas a dicha rama:

```sh
git checkout master
```

Y luego hayas hecho un `merge` desde allí:

```
git merge dev
```

Puedes revisar la [documentación de Git](https://git-scm.com/docs) (en inglés) para ampliar un poco más sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias. Mi duda era referente al área de trabajo, si al crear un archivo en la rama dev o una carpeta, el archivo o carpeta serían visibles en todas las ramas, siempre hablando del área de trabajo. 

Sé que en el momento de hacer git add y luego un commit, el archivo sólo será visible en la rama donde fue creado y hecho el commit. 

La duda que tenía era referente al área de trabajo no al índice o repositorio. 

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Me autorespondo. Aquí info en inglés. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471400/why-are-changes-in-one-branch-visible-in-another-branch

Tenemos dos ramas:

1. master
2. dev

Si estamos en la rama dev y creamos un archivo o carpeta y luego nos movemos a la rama master, veremos el archivo o carpeta que hemos creado en la rama dev, por qué, porque estamos dentro del área de trabajo o working directory y git no hace nada en esta área.

Recapitulando. Cualquier archivo o carpeta creado en una rama x, será visible en todas las ramas y sólo desaparecerá hasta que lo pasemos al staging area o hagamos un commit.

Ojo, esto es porque tenía una duda y estuve haciendo pruebas. No es una buena practica, si haces un cambio estando en una rama, no es recomendable cambiar de rama sin haber guardado los cambios.